# How can I bring back the old menu style on Chrome 28 onwards, now that the --disable-new-menu-style switch has been removed?

Tags: google-chrome

It used to be that the new, super wide, touch friendly context menu style that Google introduced a few versions of Chrome ago could be turned off using the start up flag "--disable-new-menu-style".

As of Chrome 28, this is no longer the case, and as a desktop user it is very irritating to see menus that previously fit in the screen not to do so anymore — I don't think I can get used to it. Is there any way around it? If the flag is gone for good, can the style of the context menus be perhaps edited with custom css like the web inspector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Chrome 28.0.1500.72 (Official Build 211400) the following switch activates a new style with much less vertical padding:

> --force-fieldtrials="NewMenuStyle/Compact2/"

No idea whether that switch is there to stay but it does indicate Google is working on this.

Comment: Yup, it works.  Unfortunately it also collapses the row of extension icons.  Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

Google has [made clear](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/a1HEE-7bjlA%5B1-25-true%5D) that they've made an arbitrary decision to do this and aren't interested in revisiting it.  A Google flack named JackyH told us this and marked her own answer as "best" for the topic, even though readers have downvoted her answer 8 to 121.

So, sorry, but no solution is forthcoming from Google, although it wouldn't hurt to add your downvote to JackyH's answer and your complaint to the long list of them.

Comment: Do we know whether the style of the menu is hardcoded in Chromium? If only we could edit some custom CSS to change the padding that'd work too.

Comment: Today (July 24th) Chrome updated (v 28.0.1500.72) and it has reverted back to "normal" padding... apparently they flipped on the decision, or they've accidentally changed it. Also the answer you mention (from JackyH) has now been change to mention that they've reverted it...

Answer (score -4):

go to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\" rename chrome.exe into something else like new_chrome.exe, rename old_chrome.exe to chrome.exe and you can use the switch "--disable-new-menu-style" again after you restarted chrome. Google just turns into even a worse comopany than microsoft...

Comment: I've been using it for a while, the problem is that this switch no longer works in the latest version of Chrome, hence my question.