# Way to force Google Chrome (28) to use space-saving menu design

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, chromium

Since Chrome updated to Version 26 it uses per default a menu design (options, contex menu & fav folder) that needs a litte bit more space.

New design: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxrLm.png

Old design: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGckp.png

But this litte bit more space makes the difference for me. I don't like it and want to use the old space-saving menu design. The solution was to start Chrome with the `--disable-new-menu-style` flag, but this flag no longer works in Chrome 28.

Hopefully there a some other people who also prefer the old and space-saving menu design and help me to find a solution for this problem.

Comment: From what I've seen, there are lots of other people that prefer the old design, but Google has no plans to re-add the command line switch.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/619462/143613

Comment: FWIW, in Chrome 30 the new menu is more compact.