# --disable-new-menu-style flag no longer complies

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome's `--disable-new-menu-style` flag has very recently stopped working according to http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Dmdwbc4lUF8. Does anyone know of a workaround to get the regular menu style back in current versions of Google Chrome?

Google seems to have a lot of trouble understanding user feedback.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/619462/143613

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I made a duplicate, but it doesn't have the solution I was after: [How can I bring back the old menu style on Chrome 28 onwards, now that the --disable-new-menu-style switch has been removed?](https://superuser.com/questions/617641/how-can-i-bring-back-the-old-menu-style-on-chrome-28-onwards-now-that-the-dis?rq=1)